# Как вывод записей из БД присвоить переменной?

Tags: php, mysql

Дело в том, что в таком коде $result будет обращаться к БД 6 раз. Как присвоить переменной один раз, и пользоваться ею?

```
for ($j = 1; $j < 7; $j++) {
    $result = mysql_query('SELECT * from teachers');

    for ($y = 1; $y <= mysql_num_rows($result); $y++) {
        $myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result);
        echo '<option value = "' . $myrow['id'] . '">' . $myrow['Фамилия'] . '</option>';
    }
}
```

Comment: А можно ли как-нибудь результат этого куска кода 
for($y=1; $y<=mysql_num_rows($result); $y++)
{$myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo    '<option value = "'.$myrow['id'].'">'.$myrow['Фамилия'].'</option>';
}
поместить в переменную, и просто выводить ее?

Comment: Ведь по сути
foreach ($arr as $row)
{
    echo    '<option value = "'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['Фамилия'].'</option>';
}
тоже будет выполняться 6 раз.

Comment: а зачем вам выбирать ВСЁ из таблицы учителей аж целых ШЕСТЬ раз? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно так например:

```
$arr = array();
while($r = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        if($r == null)
            break;
        array_push($arr, $r);
    }
```

После чего в массиве $arr будет то что Вам нужно( если я конечно правильно понял вопрос ).
Честно сказать это не самое хорошее решение. Но надеюсь я вас натолкнул на нужный путь.

Для доступа к нужной ячейке нужно будет писать примерно так:

```
$arr[0]['teacher_name']
```

То есть если судить по вашему коду то дальше нужно делать так:

```
$i = 0;
while($i < count($arr))
{
  echo    '<option value = "'.$arr[$i]['id'].'">'.$arr[$i]['Фамилия'].'</option>';
}
```

Или используйте foreach. Он как-то симпатичней выглядит.

```
foreach ($arr as $row)
{
    echo    '<option value = "'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['Фамилия'].'</option>';
}
```

Для того чтобы поместить результат в переменную используйте конкатенацию.

```
foreach($arr as $row)
{ 
$str .= '<option value="'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['Фамилия'].'</option>';
}
```